# Изменить цвет кнопки

Tags: html, css

При нажатии на устройствах андроид, изменение цвета кнопки происходит только при удержании. Необходимо чтобы при нажатии цвет оставался.

CSS

```
  .login-btn2:active {
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: 500s ease;
  transition: 0s ease;
}

.login-btn2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #33b5e5;
  width: 50%;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="login-btn2" name="wfphshr-vk ">INSTAGRAM</button>
```

Comment: :focus по моему должен справиться с этим , или toggleClass jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** У вас ошибка в `transition`, лучше будет сделать так + `focus`:

`css`:

```
.login-btn2:focus {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.login-btn2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #33b5e5;
  width: 50%;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: 1s ease;
}
```

`html`:

```
 <button type="button" class="login-btn2" name="wfphshr-vk ">INSTAGRAM</button>
```

**2)** Либо же используя `jQuery`:

`js`:

```
$('.login-btn2').click(() => {
    this.toggleClass('colored');
})
```

`css`:

```
.colored {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.login-btn2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #33b5e5;
  width: 50%;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: 1s ease;
}
```

**3)** Либо на нативном `js`:

`js`:

```js
    document.getElementsByClassName("login-btn2")[0].addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        const el = event.target;
        el.classList.contains('colored') ? el.classList.remove('colored') : el.classList.add('colored');
    }, false);
```

```css
.colored {
  background: red !important;
}

.login-btn2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #33b5e5;
  width: 50%;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="login-btn2" name="wfphshr-vk ">INSTAGRAM</button>
```

Пример на нативном `js` [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74r6v945/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.login-btn2:focus {
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: 500s ease;
  transition: 0s ease;
}

.login-btn2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #33b5e5;
  width: 50%;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="login-btn2" name="wfphshr-vk ">INSTAGRAM</button>
```